# Are mdg:camera & mg:geolocation still up to date?

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I have been trying for the last hours or so to find this error:
`Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 6.1.1, failed version requirement: >=6.3.0`

I have already upgraded to the newest Meteor version `(1.6.0.1)` but still the same. I installed the `mag:camera` package locally and tried different Cordova-plugin versions, but without success.

Maybe I should change the Cordova version requirement in `msg:camera's package.js:
api.use("isobuild:cordova@5.2.0");`

Also I don't know how to find out the actual cordova-android version that meteor uses.

Any ideas?

Regards